# SendMessage does not work with Word app

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I am making a little aplication and I need to make a click over a position in a word document.

I am using "sendMessage, although I also was using "postMessage" getting the same result.

```
#include <Windows.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND win_handle = FindWindow(L"OpusApp", NULL);
    if (win_handle != NULL)
    {
        POINT win_coords = {1310, 360};
        POINT ctrl_coords = win_coords;

        ScreenToClient(win_handle, &win_coords);
        WCHAR windowsText1[200];
        GetWindowText(win_handle, windowsText1, 200);
        //SetCapture(win_handle);
        LPARAM lParam = MAKELPARAM(win_coords.x, win_coords.y);
        LRESULT hr_d = SendMessage(win_handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, lParam);
        LRESULT hr_u = SendMessage(win_handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Regards.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? We can't read your mind. You need to be specific in your questions here if you want us to help you.

Comment: Did you verify with Spy++ or other spy app that the "OpusApp" window is the correct window to send mouse messages to? Some apps use hidden windows.

Comment: Word has an extensive automation model. You should use that.

Comment: @KenWhite, ok I want to set the cursor in a new position from other application.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: OpusApp is the Word application className, http://users.skynet.be/am044448/Programmeren/VBA/vba_class_names.htm

Comment: @RaymondChen: I am using automation to draw shapes and write text in a word document but I am not able to set the cursor in a new position with automation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use SendMessage or PostMessage to send input. It may work for some programs, but directly sending or posting the message doesn't update the internal state that's associated with input, which can make odd things happen, such as not detecting the input.

That's why the function [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists. This injects input on the same level that the mouse driver uses, so Windows will correctly maintain its state. Of course, this is for global input. If there's no way to ensure that the window will be in the foreground, you may want to look into [UI Automation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Jon S., at the beginning I tried with SendInput in order to simulate an actual left mouse click, but the problem is that my app is always running as active window then is my own app who process the mouse event. Then I wanted to use "Send/PostMessage" in order to send the event to the Word Application.

Comment: In that case, you should use UI Automation.

Comment: At the end, I got the solution by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh780901(v=office.14).aspx. I am getting the range by using RangeFromPoint from my active windows and then range.Select. Maybe the problem was I did not make the question correctly